# What Logman Microsoft-Windows-Kernel-File trace provider flags should I use to monitor file IOPS/MBps

Tags: windows-server-2008, performance

I'm trying to analyse the load on my server down to the file level, so I can move the most active files to their own disk spindles.

I tried:

```
logman start 001 -p Microsoft-Windows-Kernel-File 0x10 0xff -ets
```

I also tried other flags, but got too much data.

How can I find out what flags to set for the logging I require?